# confuse javascript bind function

Tags: javascript

I run the below JS script but just find `func2()` output is `foobar`, not `George`, who can explain why `func2 = func.bind(someuser)` doesn't bind `someuser` to `func`?

```
var someuser = {
    name: 'George',
    func: function () {
        console.log(this.name);
    }
};
var foo = {
    name: 'foobar'
};
func = someuser.func.bind(foo);
func(); // output foobar
func2 = func.bind(someuser);
func2(); //output foobar
```

Comment: Maybe it's because its already been binded?

Comment: i don't get your question

Comment: @Shawn31313 You should post that as an answer btw.

Answer (score 4):

From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind):

> The bind() function creates a new function (a bound function) with the same function body (internal Call attribute in ECMAScript 5 terms) as the function it is being called on (the bound function's target function) with the this value bound to the first argument of bind(), **which cannot be overridden**.

Basically this means that you can't call bind on an already bound function.

In your example, you'd have to do:

```
func2 = someuser.func.bind(someuser);
```

Answer (score 2):

I think what you want is a weak bind:

```
function weakBind(functable, context) {
    var GLOBAL = this;

    return function () {
        return functable.apply(this === GLOBAL ? context : this, arguments);
    };
}
```

Now you can do this:

```
var someuser = {
    name: 'George',
    func: function () {
        console.log(this.name);
    }
};

var foo = {
    name: 'foobar'
};

var func = weakBind(someuser.func, foo);
func(); // output foobar

var func2 = weakBind(func, someuser);
func2(); //output George
```

See the demo: http://jsfiddle.net/R79EG/

---

The problem with a normal bind is that once you bind an object to the `this` pointer it can't be overridden. The weak bind checks whether the `this` pointer is set to the `GLOBAL` object (in which case the default value is used). Otherwise it uses whatever the new `this` points to.

---

BTW in your case it's simply better to do this instead:

```
var someuser = {
    name: 'George',
    func: function () {
        console.log(this.name);
    }
};

var foo = {
    name: 'foobar'
};

var func = someuser.func.bind(foo);
func(); // output foobar

var func2 = someuser.func.bind(someuser);
func2(); //output George
```

This is better than `weakBind` because calling `func2` would call `func` which would in turn call `someuser.func`. However using `bind`, calling `func2` would directly call `someuser.func`.

Comment: +1 for suggesting a solution, rather than just telling him why it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

You have already binded `someuser.func`.

You might want to setup the script differently.

Or use:

```
func = someuser.func.bind(foo);
func(); // output foobar
func2 = someuser.func.bind(someuser);
func2(); //output foobar
```

Don't try to rebind an already binded function.

Comment: "Should be:" --- why do you think so?

Comment: Because it would return "George"

Comment: are you sure you completely understand how `.bind()` works? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind

Comment: Dude you had the right answer in the comments but this makes no sense

Comment: And I do understand it. Not sure what I was doing.